# Postfix virtual alias domain matching with regular expression virtual alias map

Tags: postfix

Using Postfix (2.11.3) I want to redirect all mail to an external address.

`/etc/postfix/main.cf`:

```
virtual_alias_maps = regexp:/etc/postfix/rewrite
```

`/etc/postfix/rewrite`:

```
/^.+$/ hijacked@example.com
```

Sending mail to `destination@example.net`, the following error occurs:

```
[...] to=<hijacked@example.com>, orig_to=<destination@example.net> [...] status=bounced (User unknown in virtual alias table)
```

[Documentation](http://www.postfix.org/ADDRESS_CLASS_README.html#virtual_alias_class) says:

> Valid recipient addresses are listed with the virtual_alias_maps parameter. The Postfix SMTP server rejects invalid recipients with "User unknown in virtual alias table".

Turns out, the error has to do something with validation of virtual alias domains: `virtual_alias_domains` by default is `$virtual_alias_maps`, setting it to anything else (to a non-matching domain or even leaving it empty) resolves  the issue.

Another solution I found [in an answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/144325/how-to-redirect-all-postfix-emails-to-one-external-email-address#346804) is giving the regular expression in another form:

```
/^.+@.+$/ hijacked@example.com
```

So my question is, how does validation of alias domains works when using regular expression tables for virtual aliasing? Why does setting `virtual_alias_domains` to anything else solves the issue? How is the above two, address-mapping-wise equivalent patterns different?

Output of `postconf -n` is:

```
config_directory = /etc/postfix
inet_interfaces = loopback-only
inet_protocols = ipv4
mydestination =
myhostname = example.org
myorigin = $myhostname
virtual_alias_domains =
virtual_alias_maps = regexp:/etc/postfix/rewrite
```

Comment: Can you paste the output of `postconf -n` to help you better?

Comment: @clement sure, see my edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose here you have a mail for `destination@example.net` to be delivered.

Maps specified in `virtual_alias_domains` are looked up using the domain part (`example.net`) as a key, expected to return anything if it's a virtual alias domain, otherwise nothing i.e. that key should be undefined.  Maps in `virtual_alias_maps` are looked up using the full address (`destination@example.net`) as a key, expected to return a rewritten address.

This means you can share a single map file for both look-ups, just as simple hash map `/etc/postfix/virtual` explained in [virtual (5)](http://www.postfix.org/virtual.5.html).  The default configuration of Postfix (`virtual_alias_domains = $virtual_alias_maps`) is assuming a map of this mixed style.

```
example.net OK
aaa@example.net hijacked@example.com
bbb@example.net hijacked@example.com
```

The important rules of these look-ups are:

- `virtual_alias_maps` are recursively looked up.  If it returns the same address as the key, that address is used.
- If final rewritten address returned by `virtual_alias_maps` is still in `virtual_alias_domains`, that looking up is regarded as a failure (`User unknown in virtual alias table`).  This seems not explicitly documented, I've learned by [this thread](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mailing.postfix.users/SBzpioozUv4/wHBcrT9OV7oJ).

Therefore, your first regexp map (`/^.+$/ hijacked@example.com`) and configuration is problematic, because the map matches everything, so `hijacked@example.com` is still in `virtual_alias_domains` and gets bounced.

You could avoid it by specifying nothing in `virtual_alias_domains`, or use another regexp map that doesn't match a single domain string (`/^.+@.+$/ hijacked@example.com`).

But either of them don't look to me the correct configuration, but a kind of unintuitive workaround.  There would be more suitable solution for your purpose, I think.

Comment: Okay, perhaps I didn’t understand the purpose of `virtual_alias_domains` correctly. According to the [documentation](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#virtual_alias_domains): „Postfix is final destination for the specified list of virtual alias domains, that is, domains for which all addresses are aliased to addresses in other local or remote domains.” Does this mean that domains specified in `virtual_alias_domains` are domains addresses in are strictly aliased to local addresses? Therefore the validation of recipients and error?

Comment: Also, what would be the correct solution, in your opinion?

Comment: Okay, I think I got it. In [virtual(5)](http://www.postfix.org/virtual.5.html) it is said that „The main applications of virtual aliasing are: [...] To implement  virtual  alias  domains  where  all addresses are aliased to addresses in other domains.” So specifying a domain as a `virtual_alias_domain` serves as a restriction to ensure that every address in that domain is strictly aliased to another adress in _another_ _domain_. Correct?

Comment: @JoóÁdám Yes, probably by those definitions you found, postfix regards itself as the final destination of mails to `virtual_alias_domains`, so it wil accept such mails from external hosts but won't forward them to other hosts, those mail addresses must be resolved to addresses in other domains or local accounts by `virtual_alias_maps`.  Wish we had more intuitive diagnostic message other than `User unknown in virtual alias table`...

Comment: @JoóÁdám After all investigating, I've come to conclusion that just specifying a simple regexp map `/@/ hijacked@exmaple.com` in `virtual_alias_maps` would do the best for your job with postfix.  You could have a smtpd which is open to insiders according to `smtpd_relay_restrictions`.  For my servers I usually install [nullmailer](http://untroubled.org/nullmailer/) with `adminaddr` setting.  It provides `/usr/sbin/sendmail` and a spool for deferred mails, but no smtpd.